# Как решить такую задачу :

Tags: python

Создать словарь, где будем записывать 3 разных продукта, с переводом на английский язык . Программа спрашивает у пользователя перевод какого слова он хочет узнать. В результате программа выводит перевод слова на английском языке

Пример:

```
Введите слова 2 слова через пробел: Яблоко Apple  
Введите слова 2 слова через пробел: Стол Table  
Введите слова 2 слова через пробел: Апельсин Orange

(Распечатать словарь)

Перевод какого слова хотите посмотреть? Апельсин
Перевод: Orange
```

```
a = 0
words = {}
for _ in range(3):
  tran = input("Введите два слова через пробел:").split()

 search_tran = input("Перевод какого слова вы хотите посмотреть :")
```

Answer (score 0):

По идее, должно работать)

```
dictionary={}
for i in range(3):
    keypair=input('Введите слова 2 слова через пробел: ').split()
    dictionary[keypair[0]]=keypair[1]
query=input('Перевод какого слова вы хотите посмотреть: ')
word=dictionary[query]
print(word)
```